# How to use a Simpson 262 model 2 to measure voltage and milliamperage of solar cells

Tags: current-measurement, solar-cell, multimeter

In cleaning out my dad's garage after his death I found a Simpson 262 Model 2 meter.  As a hobby, I fix and upgrade garden and pathway solar powered LED lights. I have a box of miscellaneous solar cells --ranging in size from

In order to use them I need to know their voltage and milliamperage output.  To do that I would like to use that old Simpson meter of my dad's.  According to the manual, measuring the voltage should be straight forward --select the appropriate DC range, connect the positive and negative and read the meter.

However, the instructions for milliamperage says something about not simply connecting the lines but also something about needing a load in series and to never connect for current measurement without a load in series. What kind of load --resistor, led, or?

Also, I haven't actually used the meter yet as I have had to order a 22.5 volt battery for it.

In asking this question, I expect that readers will guess that I am not a technician of any sort --actually, I am a retired English teacher.

Comment: For the special case of solar cells, they are inherently current limited so you can safely just connect the multimeter leads. Don't try that with a battery though!

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you!

Comment: @Eddy, just be aware that there is an optimal point for using the solar cells. If you load them too much, you won't get much out of them. If you don't load them enough, you won't get much out of them. Somewhere in between there is a "spot" where they work better. (And this is light-level dependent, too.) So one measurement doesn't tell you everything you need to know. Worse, the multimeter probably won't present an optimal load. But at least it is a measurement. If you are serious, you'll need to do more, though. Nice that you found a Simpson!!

Comment: @Eddy Used to be that telephone batteries were 22.5 V and 45 V and very commonly found. (I used them for one of my very first electronic designs -- a geiger counter -- back about 50 years ago.) Not so much anymore. You can cobble them up from 1.5 V AAA or AA batteries, though. Those old ones were just a whole bunch of AA carbon batteries wired up in series.

Comment: If you take 2 x 9V ALKALINE "transistor radio batteries and push +ve of one into -ve of other they clip together and you have an 18V battery (actually over 19V when new) . A 22.5V carbon-zinc battery is (probably) 15 cells in series and probably is fully discharged at 15V. The meter will probably (again) run OK on the 2 x 9V batteries and it will not harm the meter (as long as you get the polarity correct).

Comment: The 22.5V battery is simply there to measure (higher) resistances. There may also be a 1.5V one for low resistance ranges. All other functions of the meter will work fine without any battery.